# PIC to PIC UART communication to Blink the LED

Tags: pic, uart, led

I want to send a command by PIC12F1572 to another PIC12F1572 through UART
and in that I want to send a function which will blink the LED on the slave PIC.
I have done some code but I am somewhat confusing
can anyone help me here?
P.S- I am Using MPLAB X IDE v3.50

**Master/Transmitter PIC12F1572:**

```c
    #include <xc.h>
    #include "main.h"
    #include "config.h"
    #include "TYPEDEF_Definitions.h"
    #include "PIC_12_Timer0.h"
    #include "PIC_12_UART.h"
    #include "System_init.h"
    #include "Pin_manager.h"
    #include "LED.h"

    #define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
void main()
{   
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    //pin_config();
    LATA = 0x00;  
    UART_Init();                  //Initialize UART
  // StartLedBlinkingWithColor(color);

    TRISAbits.TRISA2  = 1; //make RA2 as input

    while (1)
    {   
      //LATAbits.LATA2 = 1;
      uint8_t Var = 0x61;
       //uint8_t Var = LATAbits.LATA2;

        if(TXSTAbits.TRMT == 1)
            {

                  UART_write(LED_Blink()); // is it possible?? or how it will be possible

                 // __delay_ms(1000);
            }

       LATAbits.LATA2 = 1;


    }
}

void LED_Blink()
{
       LATAbits.LATA2   = 1; 
       LATAbits.LATA5   = 1; 

       __delay_ms(1000);


       LATAbits.LATA2   = 0; 
       LATAbits.LATA5   = 0;


}
```

**RECEIVER/SLAVE PIC12F1572:**

```c
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"
#include "PIC_12F_GPIO.h"
#include "Led.h"
#include "Interruptmanage.h"
#include "PIC_12F_UART.h"
#include "PIC_12F_TIMER0.h"
#include "main.h"

void main( void)
{
    uint8 data;   

    InterruptInit();
    TIMER0_Init();
    UART_Init();
    InitLeds(); // here I init GPIO pin..no prb here

    // SetLedOff();

    /*-------------R E C E I V E R*------------*/
    while (1) 
    {   // Endless loop

        if (UART_DataReady() )     // I get prob here ..
        { 
          PORTA = UART_ReadOneByte(); // read the received data, [how can I receive my Led_Blink() function??
          LATAbits.LATA2   = 1;      
          //LATAbits.LATA2 = data;

          //SendByteSerially(data);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could be an interesting question, but it is currently unclear what specifically you are asking. What did you expect, and how is your code working differently? Have a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for some guidance.

Comment: okay.now  I want to send a led_blink() function through UART so that this function will blink the LEDs on other PIC..in short I want to control the Blinking of LEDs..I edit the the above code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for Receiving data from UART and saving it in array and use the data to vlink nthe LED I Have done this code: Anyone interested can have a look

```
 while (1)
 {

        if (EUSART_DataReady)
        {
            for (i = 0; i<FRAMESIZE; i++)   //#define FRAMESIZE 19
            {
                RX_Buffer[i] = EUSART_Read();
                if (RX_Buffer[i] == '\n')        //check'\n' in the end of frame
                   break;
            }

            RX_Buffer[i] = '\n';                        //append '\n' at the end of stoaring array for detection of frame
            RX_Buffer[i+1] = '\0';                      // End of an array
            EUSART_WriteAnArrayOfBytes(RX_Buffer);


        if(RX_Buffer[0]=='R' && RX_Buffer[FRAMESIZE-2] == '\n')   //check for correct frame
          {

            LATAbits.LATA2 = 1;
            __delay_ms(2000);
            LATAbits.LATA2 = 0;
            __delay_ms(1000);
          }
        }

  }
```

Comment: Nice work. Be careful with the lines `RX_Buffer[i] = '\n';` and `RX_Buffer[i+1] = '\0';` - if your `RX_Buffer` is `FRAMESIZE` bytes long, you can actually write **beyond the end** of the buffer - this is what we call [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Comment: Please upvote me guys then I can not post new queries anymore...My quota is complete..

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to consider:

- You cannot "send a function" through the UART. Therefore, the `LED_Blink()` function needs to be on the receiver side. Before doing anything else, verify that the function works on the receiver side, without any UART interaction.
- Next, you can define a [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.orgwiki/Communications_protocol), which is basically deciding which byte values you send through the UART should trigger the `LED_Blink()` call on the receiver side. For example, if you decide to use the byte value of 42 to trigger a LED blink, your sender would call `UART_write(42)` and on the receiver side, you would have something like the following:

  ```
  data = UART_ReadOneByte();
  if (data == 42) {
      LED_Blink();
  }
  ```

Comment: thank you @FriendFX I got this part and now I have new doubt  I have to send a frame command lets say in the format ...RGBXXYYZZMAABBCCDD  in which the RGBis fix value and XXYYZZ are RGB  hex vakue and M is mode of LED like blink or glow and A B C is hex value for glowing intensity,,How can it send by UART..I will be thankful if you hav any solution or hint..:) I have writen this function for this            `void UART_WriteAnArrayOfBytes(uint8 *data, uint8 length)
{
  uint8 i;

  for(i = 0; data[i] !='\0'; i++)
  {
      UART_WriteOneByte(data[i]); 
  }
}`

Comment: Don't you have to connect the LED to a D-A or A-D of some sort to do that?

Comment: @Garryp, that would be a new question - you can create a new one and write a comment here with the link to it, so I'll have a look. Also please don't forget to [mark my answer as "accepted"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved the question for you :-)